# AWS load client credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to write my first Scala lambda, and running into a problem trying to load my credentials for Phoenix Db queries.

I'm using the following (which has been used by other developers) to load the credentials automajically.

```
    libraryDependencies += "org.scalikejdbc" %% "scalikejdbc" % "3.4.0"

    import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ec2.Ec2Client._

    val client = Ec2Client.builder()
              .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
              .build()
    val response = Try(client.describeInstances(request))
```

This will get me the following error when trying to reference client in anyway:

```
DEBUG software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsCredentialsProviderChain - Unable to load credentials from SystemPropertyCredentialsProvider(): Unable to load credentials from system settings. Access key must be specified either via environment variable (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID) or system property (aws.accessKeyId).
software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to load credentials from system settings. Access key must be specified either via environment variable (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID) or system property (aws.accessKeyId).
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException$BuilderImpl.build(SdkClientException.java:97)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.internal.SystemSettingsCredentialsProvider.resolveCredentials(SystemSettingsCredentialsProvider.java:58)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsCredentialsProviderChain.resolveCredentials(AwsCredentialsProviderChain.java:91)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.internal.LazyAwsCredentialsProvider.resolveCredentials(LazyAwsCredentialsProvider.java:52)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.DefaultCredentialsProvider.resolveCredentials(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:98)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsClientHandlerUtils.createExecutionContext(AwsClientHandlerUtils.java:70)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.createExecutionContext(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:68)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:68)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.SdkSyncClientHandler.execute(SdkSyncClientHandler.java:44)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.execute(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:55)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.services.ec2.DefaultEc2Client.describeInstances(DefaultEc2Client.java:9557)
...
...
...
```

Now, the weird part is that I can do it load for DynamoDb and query just fine.

```
  val client: AmazonDynamoDB = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().build()
  val dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client)  //this works just fine.
```

Can anyone suggest what I might be missing to get the credentials to load?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an error, it is an internal debug message from the AWS SDK. It is logged [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/blob/master/core/auth/src/main/java/software/amazon/awssdk/auth/credentials/AwsCredentialsProviderChain.java#L100), and if you look a few lines above you'll see this comment:

```
// Ignore any exceptions and move onto the next provider
```

Not necessarily the best coding practice, but nothing that you have to worry about. I recommend disabling DEBUG-level logging for `software.amazon.awssdk`.

> Now, the weird part is that I can do it load for DynamoDb and query just fine

That's because the SDK found the credentials provider when you created the EC2 client, and reused it to create the DynamoDB client.

Comment: I actually do the dynamoDb first and it works, then the ec2Client fails.

Comment: @Limey - I don't know how your program is structured, but the point that it remains is that it's internal debug logging. Does your `Try` execute successfully, or do you get an exception?